# How can I enforce brackets in a transform statement with sass?

Tags: sass, css-transforms

I would like to build a transform statement dynamically in sass (as a mixin parameter) and I am unsure how to enforce the brackets.

```
$dir: translateY;
$val: 42;
$i: 3;

.test {
  transform: #{$dir}(#{$val * $i}) scale(1);
}
```

should transform into

```
.test {
  transform: translateY(126) scale(1);
}
```

It does exactly this under libsass, but unfortunately I can not use it in this project. On the other hand I could do it using `@if`statements, but that doesn't feel the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to quote it and then use interpolation again:

```
$dir: translateY;
$val: 42;
$i: 3;

.test {
  // either of these will work
  transform: #{'#{$dir}(#{$val * $i})'} scale(1);
  transform: #{$dir}#{'(#{$val * $i})'} scale(1);
}
```